# POST parameter seems to be getting set to 0, thus throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an issue where `subscriber[:job_id]` is at first correct but is then getting set to `0`.

```
#controllers/subscribers_controller.rb
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)
    puts subscriber_params #THIS OUTPUTS {"job_id"=>"EtcaA1a1p00J", "email"=>"test@test.com"}
    puts @subscriber #THIS OUTPUTS <Subscriber:0x007fa36c88c658>  
    puts @subscriber.job_id #THIS OUTPUTS 0
    puts @subscriber.email #THIS OUTPUTS test@test.com
    @job_id = subscriber_params[:job_id]
    result = NewSubscriptionService.(subscriber: @subscriber, job_id: @job_id)
    if result.success?
      redirect_to result.job, success: 'You will be notified of changes to this job.'
    else
      redirect_to result.job, alert: 'Sorry, we were not able to subscribe you to this job.'
    end
  end

  def subscriber_params
    params.require(:subscriber).permit(:job_id, :email)
  end

end
```

Which outputs:

```
#console output
app/controllers/subscribers_controller.rb:6:in `create'
Started POST "/subscribers/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-16 10:28:08 -0600
Processing by SubscribersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zAj1bFJSrxkngxlybsib7/S7b+xAXouuXonujnFSELQkk3j3akG5rhnzK0g2URR/P3Z5v33KCIjOWiwi3A8F0w==", "subscriber"=>{"job_id"=>"EtcaA1a1p00J", "email"=>"test@test.com"}, "commit"=>"Watch this job"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "subscribers" ("job_id", "email", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["job_id", 0], ["email", "test@test.com"], ["created_at", "2018-05-16 16:28:08.523325"], ["updated_at", "2018-05-16 16:28:08.523325"]]
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 63ms (ActiveRecord: 6.3ms)



ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "subscribers" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_2090f82b35"
DETAIL:  Key (job_id)=(0) is not present in table "jobs".
: INSERT INTO "subscribers" ("job_id", "email", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"):

app/services/new_subscription_service.rb:14:in `perform'
app/services/new_subscription_service.rb:10:in `call'
app/controllers/subscribers_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

The params are being passed to a service object:

```
#services/new_subscription_service.rb
class NewSubscriptionService

  def initialize(params)
    @subscriber = params[:subscriber]
    puts params[:subscriber] #THIS OUTPUTS <Subscriber:0x007fa36c88c658>  
    puts params[:subscriber][:job_id] #THIS OUTPUTS 0
    puts @subscriber.job_id #THIS OUTPUTS 0
    @job_id = params[:job_id]
    @job = Job.find_by(hash_id: @job_id)
  end

  def self.call(params)
    new(params).perform
  end

  def perform   
    if subscriber.save
      OpenStruct.new(success?: true, subscriber: subscriber, job: job, error: nil)
    else
      OpenStruct.new(success?: false, subscriber: subscriber, job: job, error: subscriber.errors)
    end
  end

  private

    attr_reader :job_id, :job, :subscriber

end
```

Am I doing something wrong in `NewSubscriptionService` that is causing `job_id` to change? `email` survives every time, so I'm not sure what is happening to `job_id`.

Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: you need to pass the object not the value.

Comment: NewSubscriptionService.perform(@subscriber)

Comment: does `params[:job_id]` carries the correct value from `initialize` method? Try puts it. Maybe `params[:subscriber]` already includes job_id?

Comment: I mean, what does `puts params[:subscriber]` gives?

Comment: maybe it's how you define your `job_id` attribute. Obviously, params return a string (`"job_id"=>"EtcaA1a1p00J"`) but you request convert it into an integer

Comment: `puts params[:subscriber]` gives me `#<Subscriber:0x007fa36c88c658>` and `puts params[:subscriber][:job_id]` immediately after, gives me the `0`.

Comment: @Stephen According to your logs, the params you send to the subscribers_controller (here `Started POST "/subscribers/create"` in your logs) are not the same you pass to `NewSubscriptionService.new(...)` (inside the create action i guess)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, @sovalina. I realize they're not the same… that's what I'm trying to get to the bottom of. Why are they different? Why does `job_id` become `0`?

Comment: If i read your logs correctly `NewSubscriptionService.new` is trigger inside the "subscribers#create" action which receives the params. What do you pass to "NewSubscriptionService.new(*here*)" ?

Comment: I also posted the controller file. There, you can see I'm calling `NewSubscriptionService.(subscriber: @subscriber, job_id: @job_id)` (which is shorthand for `NewSubscriptionService.call(subscriber: @subscriber, job_id: @job_id)`)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `NewSubscriptionService.new` in your controller, you pass 2 parameters.
Just change your service's `initialize` method with these params:

```
#controller
result = NewSubscriptionService.new(@subscriber, @job_id)

# service
def initialize(subscriber, job_id)
  @subscriber = subscriber
  @job_id = job_id
  @job = Job.find_by(hash_id: @job_id)
end
```

**edit** : btw, if you want to keep a hash, then pass an hash and not 2 params

```
NewSubscriptionService.({ subscriber: @subscriber, job_id: @job_id })
```

Comment: No go. I added some more `puts` to my OP. In `subscribers#create`, `job_id` is zero immediately following `Subscriber.new`.

Comment: @Stephen but what is your `job_id` attribute type in `subscribers` table ? is it a string or an integer ?

Comment: Ugh! It's `bigint`. I would have expected a clearer error message. Thanks. This gives me a good path to stumble down.